# Mock Locale using Mockk

Tags: android, mockk

I'm trying to use [Mockk](https://mockk.io/) to mock the call to `Locale.getDefault()`, however I can't seem to get it working. Has anyone successfully used `Mockk` to mock the `Locale`?

My very simple test class

```
@Test
fun testName() {
    val defaultLocale = mockk<Locale>()

    mockkStatic(Locale::class)

    every { Locale.getDefault() } returns defaultLocale
}
```

The error I get

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no need to mock Locale as it is part of the Java framework and will run in a Unit Test without issue.

```
package java.util.Locale.java
```

If you are testing various locales you can set the desired locale before each test runs by calling `Locale#setDefault` with either one of the predefined country constants in the Locale class or enter the language and country code strings into the constructor:

```
setDefault(Locale.US) 
setDefault(Locale.GERMANY)
setDefault(Locale.FRANCE)

// with a language code
val locale = Locale("en-US")

// with a language and country code
val locale = Locale("en", "US") 

Locale.setDefault(locale)
```

**Important**

You should reset the locale after each test class has finished to ensure the locale is in an expected state for the next tests that are about to be run. This can be maintained by storing the locale the class enters with and reverting to it after all the tests have run, with the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` JUnit method annotations that run once before the classes tests run and once after all tests have run.

```
private lateinit var storedLocale: Locale

@BeforeClass
fun beforeClass() {
    storedLocale = Locale.getDefault()
}

..
// various tests that manipulate the default locale
..

@AfterClass
fun afterClass() {
     Locale.setDefault(storedLocale)
}
```

Comment: I think the correct format is ```Locale("en", "US")```

Comment: The examples in my answer pass a language code as argument to Locale constructor which in-turn calls the constructor you've mentioned. With regards to testing locale both are correct to use depending on whether you pass a language code or the language and country. I'll add some more examples to my answer..

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't answer the question asked directly, I agree with the suggestion that Locale shouldn't be mocked and we should use an existing Locale, example `Locale.US`.